# My while-loop in Swift won't terminate, what am i missing?

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop

I have a pretty detailed while-loop and have been really resisting having to ask for help once again but I am at a loss! I really apologize for this while-loop code, there's a lot going on but I don't want to leave anything out just in case you viewers require to see it all.

```
func retRhoCurrent() -> Double {
        while abs(pTarget - pCalc) > 1 {

            //
            // SET rhoCurrent
            //

            if (pTarget > pCalc) {
                rhoLow = rhoCurrent
                if(rhoCurrent >= rhoHigh) {
                    rhoCurrent += RHO_C
                    rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                } else {
                    rhoCurrent += ((rhoHigh - rhoCurrent)/2)
                }
            } else {
                rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                rhoCurrent += ((rhoLow - rhoCurrent)/2)
            }

            //
            // SET rhoR
            //

            rhoR = rhoCurrent / RHO_C

            //
            // SET DIFFERENTIAL
            //
            diffAggregate = 0
            for var kIndex = 0; kIndex < NK_VALUES.count; ++kIndex {
                diffSegment = NK_VALUES[kIndex]
                diffSegment *= pow(rhoR, IK_VALUES[kIndex])
                diffSegment *= pow(tempR, JK_VALUES[kIndex])
                iFactor = 0
                if LK_VALUES[kIndex] > 0 {
                    diffSegment *= exp(-1 * pow(rhoR, LK_VALUES[kIndex]))
                    iFactor = LK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(rhoR, LK_VALUES[kIndex])
                }
                if PK_VALUES[kIndex] > 0 {
                    diffSegment *= exp(-1 * PK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(rhoR, 2) - BK_VALUES[kIndex] * pow(tempR - UK_VALUES[kIndex], 2))
                    iFactor = 2 * rhoR * PK_VALUES[kIndex] * (rhoR - 1)
                }
                diffAggregate += (diffSegment * (IK_VALUES[kIndex] - iFactor))
            }

            //
            // SET pCalc
            //
            zDiff + 1 + diffAggregate
            pCalc = zDiff * R_CONST * 1000 * tempK * rhoCurrent
        }
        return rhoCurrent
    }
```

I guess another question i have also is the main value I want out of this while loop is rhoCurrent (as I will use this final # to calculate something else). Doing the "return rhoCurrent" will work, correct?

Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: A couple of quick comments: 1) where do you set pTarget value? 2) it seems that this is more about the algorithm than a programming problem.  Maybe outputting values will help see if this is converging as you expect or you have a logical problem...

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what do you observe happening? What is a typical value of `pTarget`? Does `pCalc` approach that value as the loop iterates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intended this line to assign a value, but it doesn't:

```
zDiff + 1 + diffAggregate
```

Because it doesn't assign a value, `diffAggregate` is not used in the body of your `while` loop. `rhoR` is also not used because of this. Your function can be simplified as such:

```
func retRhoCurrent() -> Double {
        while abs(pTarget - pCalc) > 1 {

            //
            // SET rhoCurrent
            //

            if (pTarget > pCalc) {
                rhoLow = rhoCurrent
                if(rhoCurrent >= rhoHigh) {
                    rhoCurrent += RHO_C
                    rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                } else {
                    rhoCurrent += ((rhoHigh - rhoCurrent)/2)
                }
            } else {
                rhoHigh = rhoCurrent
                rhoCurrent += ((rhoLow - rhoCurrent)/2)
            }

            //
            // SET pCalc
            //
            pCalc = zDiff * R_CONST * 1000 * tempK * rhoCurrent
        }
        return rhoCurrent
    }
```

---

I'm really suspicious of the variables that you use in the loop but do not initialize within the function. What are the initial values for `rhoLow`, `rhoHigh`, `rhoCurrent`, `tempK`, `zDiff`, `pTarget`, and `pCalc`?

This method is very messy and depends on a lot of magic. It is modifying values that it does not own, meaning you could experience unexpected things in other areas of your app. It is definitely not thread-safe (though this may not be a concern for you).

Comment: Hi Ian, WOW! I can't believe I missed that simple error...good eye! For my variables rhoLow, rhoHigh, rhoCurrent, etc...I've initially set them equal to zero. The pTarget is the only one that has an initial value from user inputted pressure. I will try fixing that one line and see if it correctly outputs what I am looking for. Again, thank you for taking the time looking through my mess of code

Comment: The part where he is modifying variables not held by this scope within the scope. If the method is called simultaneously on two different threads, they could both independently change the value of `rhoHigh` (for example) and mess up the remainder of the loop for the other thread.

Comment: @Matty: when you initially set `zDiff` to `0` and don't give it a new value (possibly because of a typo), your final assignment to `pCalc` always evaluates to `pCalc = 0`. Unless `pTarget` is within `-1` to `1`, your while loop will never exit.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Update: By changing the line you caught, I was able to get it to solve! The pCalc is calculated after the first iteration, so it does change (the last second-last line in the code sets it to an initial value after its first run through). Did you by-chance miss this? You may also be 100% correct and I might've just gotten lucky from my first try.

Comment: `pCalc` does not change if `zDiff` is always set to `0` as would have been the case before you corrected your typo. `pCalc = 0 * R_CONST * 1000 * tempK * rhoCurrent` is the same as `pCalc = 0`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ohhh I see what you're saying now. What the zDiff line should have been is "zDiff = 1 + diffAggregate" Yeah you're absolutely right. Thanks again for your help Ian!